# How can i get the time of the pc in format of: hours,minutes,seconds,miliseconds?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image mScreenImage = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            ffmp.PushFrame((Bitmap)mScreenImage);
            mScreenImage.Dispose();
        }
```

I have this timer tick event with interval of 40ms.
I want to get each time the time clock time of the pc each 40ms.

for example if the time now is 1:00 AM so i want to see eavery 40ms:

1:00:00:40 then 1:00:00:80 and so on...

Beside this i want also to make a timer that will go forward and show me also each 40ms in the timer tick event.

00:00:00:40....00:00:00:80...

How can i do it in the timer tick event ?

Comment: Is this just `string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output the datetime using to string to format it.

```
var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ff");
```

This will replace `h` with hours, `m` with minuses `s` with seconds and `f` with fractions of a second (milliseconds). You can further change this format to suit your needs.

For more details see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: note: the OP used `:` in the actual examples, and you probably mean `HH`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the time:

```
string formatedTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime.Now` property with a format specifier:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your timer

```
timer.Interval = 400;
```

And your timer tick event .. assumed in your label ..

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label.Text = Label1.Text = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss:ff");
    }
```